# Product page broken after upgrade to 2.3.2

Tags: magento2.3, frontend

We have recently upgraded Magento 2.3.0 to 2.3.2 and the frontend on product pages is broken.

The rest of the site appears to be working ok, but the product page is just loading a gallery loader, saying "Skip to the end of the images gallery"

You can view an example product page here:

https://staging.propmasters.net/dinosaurs-1991

Looking at the source, it appears the  isn't being loaded by the site.

The Current application mode is in developer, but it has always been in this mode, as we haven't launched it yet.

Comment: Please check the Magento mode, `bin/magento deploy:mode:show`

Comment: check is any logs?

Comment: Check the catalog_product_view.xml layout file once. I could see, your header, footer is not loaded on the detail page, which means an error in the XML layout file might be.

Answer (score 0):

Please go into your Database and check whether attribute "page_layout" and "options_container" are custom of any theme.
Then, try deleting those two attribute values.
Let me know if it works!

Comment: Thanks but this hasn't fixed it